# php-fpm + nginx issue: variable too big cause 502 error

Tags: nginx, frameworks, php

I'm creating a blog site using php framework

when I loaded all comments into a variable and pass into view

then echo the data cause 502 error, I found this error in /var/log/php5-fpm.log:

[25-Dec-2013 17:42:39] WARNING: [pool www] child 30701 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 59.483248 seconds from start

[25-Dec-2013 17:42:39] NOTICE: [pool www] child 30720 started

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEGV is a segmentation fault in your program. You need to turn on core dumps and use gdb to see where the fault is. if that child only runs your app, 60 seconds is a long time to read comments and echo so maybe you have a runaway loop?